# Is possible to write anything to one file using ">>" when the file is used by other application at the same time on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, text-files, winston, writefile

I am trying to redirect the output of two applications to the same file. Actually they are log files.

On one hand I am using the `winston` module within Node. On the other hand I am running at the same time an application from console and I redirect the output. I do this with the operator `>>`.

```
command >> file 2>&1
```

On linux it works well, but it does not work on Windows. I get this error:

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Is there a way to force the access of the second application?? It would be easier to debug my application if I had only one file. If this is not possible I will have to use two files.

NOTE: I just want to append information to the file.

**Update**

This is how I am using the logger file with the winston module in the Node application. This is the file `logging.js`

```javascript
const loc = require('locations');
const winston = require('winston');

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.File)({
            formatter: function(options) {
                var date = new Date();
                var str_date = date.toISOString().replace(/T|Z/g, ' ')
                return str_date + 'NODE - ' + options.level.toUpperCase() +' '+ (options.message ? options.message : '') +
                    (options.meta && Object.keys(options.meta).length ? '\n\t'+ JSON.stringify(options.meta) : '' );
            },
            json: false,            // because this bug: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/545
            filename: loc.debug_file_lin, 
        })
    ]
});

module.exports = logger
```

And I call the logger in the rest of js files like this

```javascript
const logger = require('logging');
```

Comment: It depends entirely upon how the reading process has the file opened (whether its open for exclusive access or not).  If you can show us the code for the processes that are reading the file, perhaps we can help.  Without fixing that, you can't "force" it.

Comment: OK, I updated my question with the code I am using in Node

Comment: I don't really know.  There are options you can specify for the winston file logger opening that will allow you to control/specify file access modes.  What you are looking for is the ability to set the mode to something that will allow another process to have write access to the file.  Though this article is for linux, it shows the option: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/688.  It's also not clear whether having two processes appending to the same file is something that can be done without race conditions (jumbled data from the two processes).